# Angular combine HTTP responses but also act individually per response

Tags: angular, http

On one hand, I have a logic which sends multiple HTTP requests and uses all responses to calculate some other values. For this, I'm using forkJoin

Basically, my code looks something like this:

```
const httpCalls = [];
//for iteration here obtaining the artist variable
httpCalls.push(this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '?method=artist.getsimilar&mbid=' + artist.mbid).map(res => res.json()).delay(i * 1000));
//after the for iteration
forkJoin(httpCalls).subscribe((similarResult : any) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < similarResult.length; i++){
//and the rest of the code goes here
```

This works well.

On the other hand I also want to increment a loading progress bar after each HTTP requests finishes. forkJoin is triggered only after all requests are processed, so it's of no use. I need to know exactly when each HTTP request finishes.

How should I achieve this, keeping in my mind also my need to combine all results?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share that shows what you have done to achieve your goal?

Comment: I already posted code for forkJoin. I can post code for the second point that I want to achieve but it will not work of course. I will post it later as I am not in front of my PC how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine two observables and receive the individual notifications with the [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zey9gd) for a demo.

```
merge(...httpCalls).subscribe(
  res => { console.log("Received: " + res); },
  error => { console.log("Error: " + error); },
  () =>  { console.log("Complete!"); });
```

---

As you mentioned in a comment, if the responses must be processed in the same order as the observables in the array, you can combine the observables with the `concat` operator (see [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygr3r8)):

```
concat(...httpCalls).subscribe(
  res => { console.log("Received: " + res); },
  error => { console.log("Error: " + error); },
  () =>  { console.log("Complete!"); });
```

Comment: This is helpful, what I forgot to mention is that the order of the responses is also important. forkJoin preserved the order, so the responses came in the same order as the requests (but didn't emit individual responses). I see that merge generates responses not necessarily ordered. I came by concat. I see the responses are generated individually and in order, so it should be what I'm looking for - will test in the next coming days.